# Want to parse HTML document on bash shell

Tags: bash, awk, sed, html-parsing

Here is the document
file.txt

```
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/release/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459">7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459> <a href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/inconsistency/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459"><i title="Inconsistency detected! Click for more details" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i></a></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-22T17:34:59Z">3 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/release/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611">7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611> <a href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/inconsistency/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611"><i title="Inconsistency detected! Click for more details" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i></a></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-22T13:56:11Z">3 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/release/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342">7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342> <a href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/inconsistency/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342"><i title="Inconsistency detected! Click for more details" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i></a></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-22T10:13:42Z">3 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/8.10.0-0.-/release/8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705">8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-19T16:47:05Z">6 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/9.11.0-0.nightly-ppc64le/release/9.11.0-0.-2021-08-11-224744">9.11.0-0-2021-08-11-224744></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2021-08-11T22:47:44Z">8 months ago</td>
```

I want to have output as

```
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459 2022-04-22T17:34:59Z
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611 2022-04-22T13:56:11Z
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342 2022-04-22T10:13:42Z
8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705 2022-04-19T16:47:05Z
9.11.0-0-2021-08-11-224744 2021-08-11T22:47:44Z
```

Is there any easy way to do that? I also want to sort them according to universal time zone
I tried

```
cat file.txt |grep "<td" | grep "href=" | sed 's/<\/a//' |awk  'BEGIN{FS="href="}{print $2}'  | awk 'BEGIN{FS=">"}{print $2} {print $5} {print $6}
```

But it's not giving desired output

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Also experts always advice to use languages which know how to parse html in case you don't have that facility(to install packages or use latest languages) you could use this one, but again this is clearly written and tested with shown samples only.

Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Using its [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content) function where we can use regex to decide whichever fields we need for our uses, it will only  make fields in lines which are satisfying the pattern(regex) and ignore others(not required ones).

```
awk -v FPAT='a class="[^"]*" href="/[^"]*|<td title="[^"]*' '
{
  num1=split($1,arr1,"/")
  num2=split($2,arr2,"\"")
  print arr1[num1],arr2[num2]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's|\([^/]*/\)\{4\}[^>]*>\([^>]*\).*title[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*|\2 \3|' input_file
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459 2022-04-22T17:34:59Z
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611 2022-04-22T13:56:11Z
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342 2022-04-22T10:13:42Z
8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705 2022-04-19T16:47:05Z
9.11.0-0-2021-08-11-224744 2021-08-11T22:47:44Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your document is legal HTML then if not forbidden you should use HTML parser rather than `grep` or `sed` or `awk`. If this is not possible then you can use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/release/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459">7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459> <a href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/inconsistency/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459"><i title="Inconsistency detected! Click for more details" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i></a></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-22T17:34:59Z">3 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/release/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611">7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611> <a href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/inconsistency/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611"><i title="Inconsistency detected! Click for more details" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i></a></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-22T13:56:11Z">3 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/release/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342">7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342> <a href="/releasestream/7.11.0-0.-/inconsistency/7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342"><i title="Inconsistency detected! Click for more details" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle"></i></a></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-22T10:13:42Z">3 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/8.10.0-0.-/release/8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705">8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2022-04-19T16:47:05Z">6 days ago</td>
 <td class="text-monospace"><a class="text-success" href="/releasestream/9.11.0-0.nightly-ppc64le/release/9.11.0-0.-2021-08-11-224744">9.11.0-0-2021-08-11-224744></td>                 <td class="text-success">Accepted</td>                 <td title="2021-08-11T22:47:44Z">8 months ago</td>
```

then

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}/){printf "%s ",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}match($0,/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file.txt
```

output

```
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-173459 2022-04-22T17:34:59Z
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-135611 2022-04-22T13:56:11Z
7.11.0-0-2022-04-22-101342 2022-04-22T10:13:42Z
8.10.0-0-2022-04-19-164705 2022-04-19T16:47:05Z
9.11.0-0-2021-08-11-224744 2021-08-11T22:47:44Z
```

Explanation: I firstly crafted 2 regular expression which do describe values we are looking for, `[0-9]` is digit, `\.` is literal dot, `{2}` is number of repetition. If first value is found I use `printf` to output that followed by space (I do not use `print` as this would add trailing newline which is unwanted), if second value is found I do `print` it.

**Disclaimer**: I assume values that you are looking for can be described using shown regular expressions and are present in each line. Feel free to adjust it to your needs. If you want to know more about `match` or `substr` read [String Functions (The GNU Awk User's Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*